# i have applied a Setonitemclicklistener on a custom list view but it doesn't do anything when i click the items

Tags: java, android

i have tried several methods to make my items clickable i have read about focus and added the lines in my XML file Relative layout. nothing seems to help. the click listener still doesn't seem to do anything for me.. please help!!!

this is my activity list view class:

```
    package com.example.trezah12.adminmodule;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdminList extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomAdapterAdmin adapterAdmin;

    ArrayList<Admin> list;
    ListView list1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_list);
        DBhandler dBhandler = new DBhandler(this);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview4);
        viewData();


        list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long Id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(AdminList.this, LaunchActivity.class);
            }
        });

    }


    private void viewData() {
        final DBhandler dbHandler3 = new DBhandler(AdminList.this);

        Cursor cursor = dbHandler3.viewData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0){


            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry no Data Found!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Admin admin = new Admin();
                admin.setUsername(cursor.getString(0));
                list.add(admin);
                list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview4);
                adapterAdmin = new CustomAdapterAdmin(list, AdminList.this);
                list1.setAdapter(adapterAdmin);

            }


        }

        }
















            }
```

below is my custom adapter class for admin:

```
package com.example.trezah12.adminmodule;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by trezah12 on 23/10/2018.
 */

public class CustomAdapterAdmin  extends BaseAdapter {


    private List<Admin> adminList = new ArrayList<Admin>();
    private Context activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


    public CustomAdapterAdmin(List<Admin> adminList, Context activity) {
        this.adminList = adminList;
        this.activity = activity;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return adminList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customeadmin, null);


        }
        Admin admin = adminList.get(position);

        TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt1.setText(admin.getUsername());

        TextView txt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txt2.setText(admin.getPassword());


        return v;
    }

 }
```

Below is my XML file for list view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because yout did not start the activity

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long Id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminList.this, LaunchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Kevin Kurien i had used a toast message earlier but that didn't show either. then i used the intent. but thank you i;ll check that again if it works now

Comment: Kevin Kurien Man u r an angel.. it worked !!! thanks a lot. u don't know how much it helped me. thanks again man..

Comment: glad I could help. If it helped you can you mark it as the right answer.cheers:D

Comment: Kevin Kurien i am new to this site. i'm sorry but i dont know how to mark the correct ans.